# what's the difference between participate and participate in?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

As in "Independent music labels also will participate, said other people familiar with the matter." and "Independent music labels also will participate in, said other people familiar with the matter."
thank you.

Comment: If you add _in_, the question is in _what_ do they participate? If you don't mention that, don't mention _in_. _I eat a burger_ is fine as a sentence. _I eat a burger in_ is not, but _I eat a burger in a restaurant_ is fine again.

Comment: Neither version makes much sense.

Comment: 'Participate in' uses a transitivising particle, so an object is mandatory, making the second example here incorrect.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There really is no difference.  Words are used as a mechanism to convey meaning, so put yourself in the shoes of someone who would use those 2 sentences.  The one who used "participate in" wants to demonstrate that they are VERY involved, they are throwing words into the mix to prove to the audience that they care. In other words the "in" is a sales tactic.

Comment: I disagree that there is no difference. A person is said to  _participate in_ an event. You would only use 'participate' on its own if you have already referred to the event, e.g. 'There will be a competition next month, in which local schoolchildren will participate'. Presumably your first sentence follows a mention of the event being described.